# SSH でポート番号を変更して接続しようとすると connection refused と表示される

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

SSHでポートを変更して接続しようとしたらターミナルに `ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port xxxxx: Connection refused` と表示されます。sshdの設定をいじる前も後もポート22だけ接続に成功します。

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` にはポートを22から別に変更してufwで別のポートを許可したのですが、通常の22番だと動くのにそのポートを指定して接続しようとすると動かなくなります。configには22以外のポートを書いてそのポートで接続しようとするとconnection refusedと表示されるのに何も指定せずに22番で接続すると問題なく繋がります。ユーザー名とIPアドレスは何度も確認しました。ConohaVPSのコンパネのポートはv4,v6共にすべて許可にしてあります。

ファイアウォールをリロードしたりサーバーを再起動したりしたのですが直らず、分かりませんでした。
どなたかご教示お願いします。

サーバー: ConohaVPS, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
接続元: Windows 11, Openssh

ポートを変更して接続失敗した時:

```
C:\Users\username\dir>ssh -p 変更したポート番号 -v username@x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port ポート番号.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port ポート番号: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port ポート番号: Connection refused
```

---

また、少し気になったのですが、configの設定ではsshからrootのログインはできないように設定しておいてあって `ssh root@x.x.x.x` で接続すると `permission denied` と表示されるのですが、sudo権限もってる一般ユーザーでssh接続してからrootでログインしたら入れたのですが、これって普通出来るんでしょうか？

Comment: ssh での接続時に `-v` オプションを追加してみると詳しい情報が表示されるはずなので、何かヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ポートを22以外に変更したが、反映されていないということでしょうか。

Comment: ちゃんとconfigにも書いて保存しましたしファイアウォールをリロードしたり、再起かけたり、sshをrestratしてみたのですがだめでした...

Comment: 追記してくれたのはデフォルトポート (22) で正常につながる場合のログのようですが、失敗する場合の情報が知りたいのでポート変更後の接続時に `-v` を付けた場合のログを追記してみてください。

Comment: 少し気になったのですが、configの設定ではsshからrootのログインはできないように設定しておいてあってssh root@x.x.x.xで接続するとpermission deniedと表示されるのですが、sudo権限もってる一般ユーザーでssh接続してからrootでログインしたら入れたのですが、これって普通出来るんでしょうか？

Comment: sshdの設定をいじる前も後も22だけ成功します

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
お恥ずかしながらconfigのポートの行がコメントアウトしてあり、気付かずそのまま使っていました。再設定後sshdを再起動したら無事接続できました。皆様色々ご教示下さりありがとうございました

Answer (score 2):

`sshd` の設定を変更したはずの後にもポート22で接続できるのなら、おそらく実際には変更できていません。ただ、複数の待ち受けポートを設定することも出来るため、まずは実際にどうなっているのか確認する必要があります。

#### `sshd` のログを確認する

`sshd` の起動時に全ての待ち受けアドレスとポートの組合せに対し、下のようなログが出ているはずです。

```
sshd[****]: Server listening on **** port ****.
```

これのポート部分を確認します。Ubuntu などの Systemd を使用したディストリビューションの場合、

```bash
journalctl -u sshd
```

で検索できると思います。

#### `sshd` の設定を確認する

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` で、

```
Port ****
```

といった記述を探します。意図しない複数の記述が有る場合は目的の一つだけ残して削除します。このような記述は `ssh` クライアントの設定でも有効なことに注意して下さい。つまり、誤って `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` に記述してしまってもエラーにはなりません。

#### サーバー上で接続の可否を確認する

対象のサーバーで、自機に対し接続します。

```bash
ssh -p 設定したはずのポート localhost
```

と、

```bash
ssh -p 22 localhost
```

のどちらで接続が成功するのか確認します。

---

#### root によるログインが禁止でも sudo は使える

sshd で root をログイン不可にしていても、一般ユーザーが ssh で接続して sudo を使うことは出来ます。これは、設定の失敗などではありません。sshd の設定と sudo の設定は別なので、問題無いことです。

Answer (score 0):

ふつう、VPSのサービスには、別個に独立したファイアウオール機能がついてたりします
そのVPSのヘルプを見るなりして、そこらへんでブロックされてないか調べてみよう